# VueJs (Quasar), vuex store access in router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, store, router

I am trying to learn Vuex and making authentication module. I was following some tutorial and got to the point when I want to use store in router. 
I am importing my store on the top of the router index.js, however I am guessing it's not importing my store as I can't access e.g. getters (undefined).

Store works fine in vue components. Why is that happening ? is it because store is not properly initialised when router is created ? According to tutorial that works fine.

router/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import routes from './routes'
import store from '../store'
Vue.use(VueRouter)

/*
 * If not building with SSR mode, you can
 * directly export the Router instantiation
 */

export default function(/* { store, ssrContext } */) {
  const Router = new VueRouter({
    scrollBehavior: () => ({ x: 0, y: 0 }),
    routes,
    // Leave these as is and change from quasar.conf.js instead!
    // quasar.conf.js -> build -> vueRouterMode
    // quasar.conf.js -> build -> publicPath
    mode: process.env.VUE_ROUTER_MODE,
    base: process.env.VUE_ROUTER_BASE,
  })
  Router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {

      if (store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
        next()
        return
      }
      next('/login')
    } else {
      next()
    }
  })
  return Router
}
```

and store/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

// import example from './module-example'

Vue.use(Vuex)
/*
 * If not building with SSR mode, you can
 * directly export the Store instantiation
 */
import state from './state'
import getters from './getters'
import mutations from './mutations'
import actions from './actions'


export default function(/* { ssrContext } */) {
  const Store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
      // example
    },
    namespaced: true,
    getters,
    mutations,
    actions,
    state,
    // enable strict mode (adds overhead!)
    // for dev mode only
    strict: process.env.DEV,
  })

  return Store
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You do not need to modified your default Quasar store/index.js

Just use it as a Promise function:

```
import store from '../store'
....
if (store().getters['auth/isLoggedIn']) {
   next()
   return
}
```

Comment: for the actions just try `store().dispatch("auth/Login")` thank you Arik :)

Answer (score 1):

I will answer it myself. My store doesn't have typical export default store,

so i modified it to below, and it works fine.

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
   authentication
  },
  namespaced: true,
  strict: process.env.DEV,
})

export default store
```

Answer (score 0):

As at 24th Feb 22 you can now...

at the top of router.js

`import { useStore } from 'vuex'`

and then within the module function

`const store = useStore()`

you then have access to `store.state` and can `store.commit('ANY_MUTATION',data)` etc,etc

Comment: Yes but that's for quasar 2 (Vue3). Original question was for Vue2 and Quasar 1

Comment: hmm tried this using quasar 2 and vue 3 and useStore() always returns undefined